# Cannot show multiple streams in opencv flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask

I'm trying to display 4 streams (2 streams works) in my opencv flask app but after displaying a frame or two, all 4 streams gets stuck, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and it's been couple of days. I have provided the necessary code below, Please have a look:

Python OpenCV Flask App:

```
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture('1.avi')
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture('2.avi')
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture('3.avi')
cap4 = cv2.VideoCapture('4.avi')

def cap1_gen():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap1.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame+b'\r\n')

def cap2_gen():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap1.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame+b'\r\n')

def cap3_gen():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap1.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame+b'\r\n')

def cap4_gen():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap1.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame+b'\r\n')

@app.route('/stream1')
def stream_cap1():
    return Response(cap1_gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/stream2')
def stream_cap2():
    return Response(cap2_gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/stream3')
def stream_cap3():
    return Response(cap3_gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/stream4')
def stream_cap4():
    return Response(cap4_gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def get_mongo_stream():
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = [x for x in mongo.db.plates.find({})]
        return render_template('index.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In `index.html`:

```
<h1>Display Streams</h1>
    <div id="cam_feed_container">
        <section>
        <div><img class="cam_feed" src="{{ url_for('stream_cap1') }}" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
        <div><img class="cam_feed" src="{{ url_for('stream_cap2') }}" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
        <div><img class="cam_feed" src="{{ url_for('stream_cap3') }}" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
        <div><img class="cam_feed" src="{{ url_for('stream_cap4') }}" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
    </section>
```

When I display only 1 or 2 streams, it shows the video running smooth but when I add more, like total 3 or 4 then the video get stuck. Can anyone help provide some solution to my problem!

Comment: this requires the server to run multiple threads.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hi, do you have an example?

Comment: I'd hope it'll do that on its own. there could also be a limit from the browser, in that the browser won't open more than ~2 concurrent connections. who knows. you need to debug this, i.e. gather more information. try watching with wireshark... you didn't say what the server says to your requests so I'll assume you like the difficult path... you could have tried opening four cameras in a standalone script that *doesn't* involve flask but that would be too obvious.